# How to filter strings from files using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse a playlist file named playlist.xml.  From this file I'd like to filter the  and .mp3 files which are included in .  There are actually numerous playlist.xml files under the $PlaylistPath.  I've tried using Get-Content, Select-String, Get-Childitem, and other cmdlets, to no avail. Shown below is my feeble attempt at using PowerShell for this purpose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$PlaylistPath = "\\MYNAS\Backups\Emby\Emby Backup - 2020-05-29 02.0.0 - Auto\playlists"
$OutputPath = "C:\Users\bernie\Desktop\playlists"

(Select-String -Path "C:\Users\bernie\Desktop\playlist.xml" -Pattern '^<Local').Line | Set-Content C:\Users\bernie\Desktop\Output.txt

# $FileNames = Get-Childitem -Path "playlists" -Include playlist.xml -File -Recurse | Select -exp Name 

#$FileNames = Get-ChildItem $PlaylistPath -Filter playlist.xml -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }

foreach ($file in $FileNames) {

(Select-String -Path $file -Pattern 'LocalTitle').Line | Write-Output
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Item>
  <Added>5/23/2020 9:49:16 PM</Added>
  <LockData>false</LockData>
  <LocalTitle>Andy Timmons Playlist</LocalTitle>
  <RunningTime>32</RunningTime>
  <Genres>
    <Genre>Pop</Genre>
    <Genre>Rock</Genre>
  </Genres>
  <Studios>
    <Studio>Favored Nations Records</Studio>
  </Studios>
  <PlaylistItems>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/01 Deliver Us.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/02 Helipad.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/05 Redemption.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Ear X-Tacy/01 - Carpe Diem.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Ear X-Tacy/05 - Farmer Sez.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
  </PlaylistItems>
 </Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell: Easily Parse XML Element Values

First, it appears the example XML content you provided is malformed so I'll assume that was just a pasting issue so I corrected that by closing the `</PlaylistItems>` and `</Items>` elements in that example.

The trick is to use [get-content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html) to read the content of the XML file and then to set that to a variable [cast as an XML data type](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html). Then you can use that variable's [DocumentElement method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement?view=netcore-3.1) to get the values from the needed elements explicitly following the rest of the element path which is just trivial.

Therefore, once you have the *playlist title or name* and *a list of the mp3 file paths*, you can use those values to go into a file or whatever but that's an easy method for parsing XML files with some control.

### PowerShell

```
$PlaylistPath = "C:\Test\zzz\TestPlayList.xml";
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -LiteralPath $PlaylistPath;

$LocalTitle = $Xml.DocumentElement.LocalTitle;
$MP3Path    = $Xml.DocumentElement.PlaylistItems.PlaylistItem.Path;

$LocalTitle;
$MP3Path;
```

---

### All `playlist.xml` Loop

```
 $PlaylistPath = "C:\Test\zzz" 
 $XMLFiles = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PlaylistPath -Include playlist.xml -File -Recurse; 
 
 $XMLFiles | % { Process {
   [xml]$xml = Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName;
   $LocalTitle = $Xml.DocumentElement.LocalTitle; 
   $MP3Path = $Xml.DocumentElement.PlaylistItems.PlaylistItem.Path;
   New-Item -Path "$OutputPath\$LocalTitle" -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
   $MP3Path | % { Copy-Item -LiteralPath "\$($_.Replace("volume1", "ds418").Replace("/", "\"))" "$OutputPath\$LocalTitle"; };  
   ##$LocalTitle; 
   ##$MP3Path;
   }};
```

### Output (using `$LocalTitle` and `$MP3Path`)

```
Andy Timmons Playlist
/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/01 Deliver Us.mp3
/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/02 Helipad.mp3
/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/05 Redemption.mp3
/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Ear X-Tacy/01 - Carpe Diem.mp3
/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Ear X-Tacy/05 - Farmer Sez.mp3
```

### The Starting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Item>
  <Added>5/23/2020 9:49:16 PM</Added>
  <LockData>false</LockData>
  <LocalTitle>Andy Timmons Playlist</LocalTitle>
  <RunningTime>32</RunningTime>
  <Genres>
    <Genre>Pop</Genre>
    <Genre>Rock</Genre>
  </Genres>
  <Studios>
    <Studio>Favored Nations Records</Studio>
  </Studios>
  <PlaylistItems>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/01 Deliver Us.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/02 Helipad.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Resolution/05 Redemption.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Ear X-Tacy/01 - Carpe Diem.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
    <PlaylistItem>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/Andy Timmons/Ear X-Tacy/05 - Farmer Sez.mp3</Path>
    </PlaylistItem>
  </PlaylistItems>
 </Item>
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Define PowerShell Data Types](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html)
- [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [XmlDocument.DocumentElement Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement?view=netcore-3.1)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach

Comment: Thank you so much!   You are correct, I am stuck trying to loop through multiple playlist.xml files,  Here's what I have which is generating a file not found error:
```
$PlaylistPath = "\\ds418\Backups\Emby\Emby Backup - 2020-05-30 02.0.0 - Auto\playlists"

$XMLFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $PlaylistPath -Include playlist.xml -File -Recurse

foreach ($file in $XMLFiles) {

   [xml]$xml = Get-Content "$file".ToString();

   $LocalTitle = $Xml.DocumentElement.LocalTitle;
   $MP3Path    = $Xml.DocumentElement.PlaylistItems.PlaylistItem.Path;

   $LocalTitle;
   $MP3Path;
}
```

Comment: Odd, I'm still getting the error below.  I thought it might be related to using a UNC path, but I changed it to a local path to the playlists.  Could the brackets in the path [playlist] be causing a problem?
       

Get-Content : An object at the specified path C:\Users\bernie\OneDrive\PowerShell\playlists\Steve Vai Playlist 
[playlist]\playlist.xml does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.
At C:\Users\bernie\OneDrive\PowerShell\GetEmbyPlaylists.ps1:16 char:15
+   [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName;

Comment: Thanks, the -LiteralPath enabled the Get-Content to function correctly.  But this resulted in paths to the .mp3 files like:

/volume1/Media Library/...

So I modified $MP3Path like this:

$MP3Path.Replace("volume1", "\ds418").Replace("/", "\");

Which results in paths like \\ds418\Media Library\...

BUT, the copy item fails because the paths need to be quoted.  Is it possible to add double quotes to the $MP3Path statement above?

-Thanks

Comment: I'm still getting a path not found error.  Here's the block of code:

$XMLFiles | % { Process {
  [xml]$xml = Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName;
  $LocalTitle = $Xml.DocumentElement.LocalTitle; 
  $MP3Path = $Xml.DocumentElement.PlaylistItems.PlaylistItem.Path; 
  
  New-Item -Path $OutputPath\$LocalTitle -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
  Copy-Item "$($MP3Path.Replace("volume1", "ds418").Replace("/", "\"))" $OutputPath\$LocalTitle;

}};

Comment: @Bernie So just be sure to use double quotes around `"$OutputPath\$LocalTitle"` and also with `Copy-Item`, you will use the `-LiteralPath` parameter with it too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll keep working on it.  Have a safe trip!

Comment: @Bernie .... I put full code here, but I think it's something along those lines and also, the UNC path needs 2 starting ``\\`` backslashes. Replacing each one forward slash ``/`` with a backslash will not give you a valid `\\server\share` UNC path. You might need to append a ``\`` to the beginning of the `$MP3Path`

Comment: The Copy-Item is trying to copy all of the files at once:

Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\ds418\Media Library\Music Library Bernie\Steve Vai\Passion and Warfare\02 Erotic 
Nightmares.mp3 \ds418\Media Library\Music Library Bernie\Steve Vai\Passion and Warfare\03 The Animal.mp3 \ds418\Media 
Library\Music Library Bernie\Steve Vai\Passion and Warfare\07 For The Love of God.mp3 \ds418\Media Library\Music 
Library Bernie\Steve Vai\Passion and Warfare\07 For The Love of God.mp3 \ds418\Media Library\Music Library 
Bernie\Steve Vai\Passion and Warfare\09 I Would Love To.mp3 \ds418\Media...

Comment: Notice only the first \\ds418 is correct, the subsequent one have only a single backslash \ds418.  I'm almost there!

Comment: @Bernie .... What's the latest when you try this using https://pastebin.com/TXXD9HbP logic? This basically loops over the `$MP3Path` array variable for the `copy-item` with all the other adjustments we've made. Hit me back and tell me how this works for you.

Comment: With your help I got this.  I'll post the answer by clicking on the "Answer Your Question" button, but cause I don't have enough characters left to complete it here...

Answer (score -1):

Pimp Juice IT,

Here are the completed loops which process the Emby playlist files, referencing the linux paths on my Synology NAS, then translating them to UNC paths understood by windows:

```
# These loops process the playlist.xml files.
$XMLFiles | % { Process { 
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName
    $LocalTitle = $Xml.DocumentElement.LocalTitle 
    Write-Host "Copying playlist music files to: " $OutputPath/$LocalTitle
    New-Item -Path $OutputPath\$LocalTitle -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    $MP3Path = $Xml.DocumentElement.PlaylistItems.PlaylistItem.Path

    # This translates the Linux literal paths required by Get-Content and Copy-Item to UNC paths accessible in 
    # Windows.  Also, most music files are prefixed with a number, cauing the playlists to out of sequence.  
    # A numeric prefix is prepended here to each music file resulting in a playing order consistent with the 
    # Emby playlist.

    $counter = 1

    foreach ($path in $MP3Path) {   
       $OutputFile = Split-Path $path -Leaf
       $OutputFile = ([string]$counter).PadLeft(2,'0') + " - " + $OutputFile 
       $OutputFile = $OutputPath + "\" + $LocalTitle + "\" + $OutputFile

       Copy-Item -LiteralPath "\$($path.Replace("volume1", "ds418").Replace("/", "\"))" $OutputFile
      
       $counter++
    }

}};


Write-Host "`nDone"
```

Comment: Why was this submitted as an answer to your question?